# How do i set my volume for my autoplay to be at a specific level?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my page i have an autoplaying piece of audio, however i need to volume to be set to a specific level just incase a user has their volume up at 100%. Any idea on how to do this

HTML Code:

```
<audio autoplay>
    <source src="Media File here">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`volume` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#attr-volume):

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay" volume="0.5">
    <source src="Media File here">
</audio>
```

> values can be from 0.0 (silent) to 1.0 (loudest)

## update

It seems like the `volume` attribute is not well-implemented, so here is a workaround:

```js
audio_tags = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')
for (var i = 0; i < audio_tags.length; i++) {
  audio_tags[i].addEventListener("loadstart", function() {
    this.volume = this.getAttribute('volume');
  }, true);
}
```

```html
<audio controls="controls" volume="0.1">
    <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Example.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<br /><br />
<audio controls="controls" volume="0.9">
    <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Example.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Says Volume is not allowed here tho?

Comment: So solution is not valid

Comment: The ide obviously

Comment: Not sure why it is obvious. Which IDE you are using?

Comment: Well why would i use textpad to write html thats stupid :D and dreamweaver

Comment: No one said you should use textpad to write HTML, it's not really not "obvious" that "says" means the IDE. It can also be your teacher :)

Comment: Regarding the dreamweaver - version?

Comment: Currently using version 17.0

Comment: even if i put it in text pad the volume does not adjust, this is using chrome

Comment: No it doesnt make a difference to the sound, Just plays at same level